# Organizing three dimensional data with awk/sed/perl

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, bioinformatics

I have this file (a sparse matrix):

```
PC.354 OTU1 6
PC.354 OTU2 1
PC.356 OTU0 4
PC.356 OTU2 7
PC.356 OTU3 3
```

I want an output like this (dense matrix -classic .biom table):

```
OTU_ID PC.354  PC.355  PC.356
OTU0   0   0   4
OTU1   6   0   0
OTU2   1   0   7
OTU3   0   0   3
```

How can I do this with awk/perl/sed? 
I found a similar question about R package (xtabs/tidyr), but I'm not used to it.

Comment: Seems it's just a question of reading the values into an array, and printing it out. More of a programming exercise than anything specifically about Unix.

Comment: hmm..could be that I'm a layman but your dense matrix appears to be a sparse matrix to me and the other way round

Comment: Its a bioinformatic subject.. I'm just using the nomenclature as they use for it (http://biom-format.org/documentation/biom_format.html)... but, anyway, its not the point of the question.

Comment: this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116011/how-to-write-header-names-based-on-value-in-columns-using-awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my (%hotu, %hpc)=();
while(<>){
  my($pc,$otu,$v)=split;
  $hpc{$pc}=1;
  ($hotu{$otu} or $hotu{$otu}={})->{$pc}+=$v;
}
#headers
my @apc = sort keys %hpc;
print join ("\t", 'OTU_ID', @apc) . "\n";
#values
foreach my $otu (sort keys %hotu) {
  print join ("\t", $otu, map {$_=0 unless defined; $_} @{$hotu{$otu}}{@apc}) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `awk`:

```
{ data[$2, $1] = $3; }
END {
    split("OTU0 OTU1 OTU2 OTU3", rows);
    split("OTU_ID PC.354 PC.355 PC.356", cols);
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        printf("%10s", cols[i]);
    }
    print "";
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        printf("%-10s", rows[i]);
        for (j = 2; j <= 4; j++) {
            item = data[rows[i], cols[j]];
            if (!item) { item = "0" };
            printf("%10s", item);
        }
        print "";
    }
}
```

Note that I have explicitly included all the rows and columns from your sample output. That is not necessary if the data actually includes all the rows and columns, which your sample data does not.